# Is "In the both cases" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, contemporary-english

I have personally never heard (or seen):

> in both cases

being referred to by:

> in the both cases

before; therefore, my first instinct was that it is an obvious mistake. However, looking up "in the both cases" (with double quotes) in Google Scholar yields many results.

So my question is: is it correct so say "in the both cases"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the both cases isn't incorrect, it just isn't used in everyday writing today which is why it *seems* wrong.
 Both is synonymous in that it refers to two nouns. 
 So, let's say we swap out both for two, the sentence would still be correct.

Comment: add citations and examples to enhance this good answer